# How can I create a complete NSDate object that represents the next specified day time?

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsdate, ios

I probably didn't word that title clearly enough, but if the user specifies a time of 2:30pm and it's currently 2:00pm, then I need an NSDate object that represents the current day with a time of 2:30pm.  If the user specifies a time of 2:30pm and it's currently 3:00pm, then I need an NSDate object that represents tomorrow with a time of 2:30pm.  Similar to how an alarm clock would work.

I already wrote this code, but it's embarrassingly long and it feels really kludgy and I feel like it should be more simple, but I'm new to iOS development and this specific API.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get userDate from the user, and `nowDate = [NSDate date]` , then

```
NSComparisonResult diff = [userDate compare: nowDate];
```

If the diff is `NSOrderedDescending`, then userDate is later than nowDate, and you set the alarm for today. If it's `NSOrderedAscending`, then you set the alarm for tomorrow. You can test for `NSOrderedSame`, but it will never be.

You'd like to avoid having to determine what day it is, so it seems to me that adding an `NSTimeInterval` of the difference plus 24 * 60 * 60 (if the alarm is tomorrow) or just the difference (if the alarm is today) would suffice.

I don't know why everyone is trying to make alarm clocks. It can't be done, as best I can tell.

Comment: With iOS 4 and local notifications, alarm clocks can be done.

Comment: You shouldn't use 24 * 60 * 60 to represent one day, use NSDateComponents and NSCalendar to add 1 day. If you use a hard coded time interval, you end up with a bunch of edge cases, e.g. if daylight savings ends, your "tomorrow" time will be off by an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have an NSDate representing the date/time the user picked?  If so, it's a pretty simple matter to compare it to now (via `earlierDate:` or `laterDate:`), and create a new one a day later (via `dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:` or `initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:`).

Something like this:

```
// Assume dateTarget is an NSDate representing the date/time the user picked.
// Is it earlier than now?
if( [dateTarget earlierDate:[NSDate date]] == dateTarget ) {
    // dateTarget is earlier than now.
    // Add 1 day to it.
    NSDate* newDate = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeInterval:60*60*24 sinceDate:dateTarget];
    [dateTarget release];
    dateTarget = newDate;
}

// dateTarget is now either the original time, or if that time passed, the same time tomorrow.
NSLog( @"dateTarget = %@", dateTarget );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a time interval that messes up around the daylight savings dates, I believe. Adding seconds for one day will then end up a day after but an hour earlier or later. I'm pretty sure I ran into this before, but you can test that easily, I guess.

Another way would be to use NSDateComponents:

```
// using while will be inefficient when the targetDate is more than a few days in the past
while ([targetDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSInteger units = NSYearCalendarUnit |
                      NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                      NSDayCalendarUnit |
                      NSHourCalendarUnit |
                      NSMinuteCalendarUnit |
                      NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:units fromDate:targetDate];
    [comps setDay:[comps day] + 1]; // if day is 32 for instance, it'll automatically roll over to the next month
    NSDate *targetDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
}
```

The above is by no means an ideal solution (it'll leak targetDate if you retained it, for instance), but is mainly meant to show you how to add 1 day to a NSDate using NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the user is using a `UIDatePicker` to select the date, here's what I would do:

```
NSDate * selectedDate = ...; //2:30pm
NSDate * selectedComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:selectedDate];

NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
NSDate * nowComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:now];

[nowComponents setHour:[selectedComponents hour]];
[nowComponents setMinute:[selectedComponents minute]];

NSDate * targetDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
if ([[now laterDate:targetDate] isEqual:now]) {
  //in a comparison between now and the target date, the target date has already passed
  [nowComponents setDay:[nowComponents day]+1];
  targetDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
}

//target date is now at the appropriate 2:30pm
```

Side note: since the `NSCalendarUnit` is a bitfield typedef for `NSUInteger`, I pass in `NSUIntegerMax` to retrieve all possible calendar units.  That way I don't have to have a massive bitwise OR statement.

Comment: question for you: if you do nowComponents setDay: day + 1, does it matter if the day is, say 32? if day is the last day of the month for example? or does everything work itself out?

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser `-dateFromComponents:` will handle unit rollovers.